# How could I change contact details in the footer?

Tags: customization, widgets, footer, contact

I somehow was able to change contact details in the footer, but now I can't find out where to edit in. Looks like widget and customization areas don't contain it.

Website: https://fito.one/about/

[image]

Comment: You can check with the theme author for documentation or support. If it's not in a widget or Customizer, it's likely in the theme files themselves.

Comment: Thanks for your help, mate. I've just found out that footer page places those blocks :)

Answer (score 0):

Turned out, it was in the `Footer` pages. I didn't know that it might be common practice though.